# Moving sparse files

Tags: files, cp, mv, sparse-files

`cp` not only auto-detects sparse files but also has `--sparse=always` option.

I wonder if `mv` works with the same mechanism or the safe way for moving sparse files is

```
cp && rm
```

Or is there any other method for moving sparse files from one disk to another?

*System info:* Ubuntu 20.04 with cp/mv (GNU coreutils) 8.30.

Comment: I suspect the definitive answer is "Use the source, Luke!" but this would almost certainly be distro-dependent. mv will use a relink within the same file system (although even this may not be required by POSIX). For cross-file-system, you might as well use cp anyway, because that's what mv would do. Rats -- the cp sparse behaviour is also probably distro-dependent.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I updated my system info for your reference. You're absolutely right, `mv` is indeed `cp && rm` for cross-disk transfer. If you post it as an answer, it can help others.